# how to obtain x86 instruction size to calculate physical address

Tags: assembly, x86, opcode, machine-code

I'm having some trouble with the variable size instructions in the CISC assembly of x86 (intel 8086).

#### Summary

I have a really limited time and I want to find the physical address of each asm source instruction in a given code segment (I presume for a MASM assembler). So I don't want to know the procedure of obtaining the exact opcodes (aka machine-code instructions).  I mean I don't need the actual bytes of each instruction after assembly, just the position.

### Problem Statement

Is there possibly a way to determine the size (e.g. 2 bytes or 3 bytes) of the opcodes of instructions without knowing the exact opcodes?. Remember the ***only*** thing I need is the ***size*** of each machine-code instruction. Basically, I'm seeking a general rule/trick to extract the size.

#### Reason

Here's an example of why there might be problems calculating the physical address regarding opcode:

```
; CS = 1132H
ORG 100H ; to prevent any misunderstanding of the physical address. OFFSET = 0100H
MOV AH, 20H ; OPCODE 2 Bytes, PhysicalAddress = 11420H (CS<<4 + OFFSET = 11320H + 100H)
ADD AX, DX  ; OPCODE 2 Bytes, PhysicalAddress = 11422H
```

`offset+2` because we store bytes in memory and the previous instruction was also 2 Bytes.

```
ADD AX, 13F5H ; OPCODE 3 Bytes, PhysicalAddress = 11424H
ADD AX, DX ; OPCODE 2 Bytes, PhysicalAddress = 11427H (and OFFSET+3 this time)
```

Here's the problem! Because of the 3-byte length of the previous instruction.  How do I know this instruction is 3 bytes long?

#### What I have done so far

I've already installed DOSBox and dosemu with both having some other problems unrelated to this one. (in both Linux and Windows). That way I could've obtained opcodes without too much worry.

#### Problem Reference

The problem begins with an assignment from (M. A. MAZIDI [THE 80x86 IBM PC AND COMPATIBLE COMPUTERS](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_80x86_IBM_PC_and_Compatible_Computer.html?id=kG9GAAAAYAAJ&source=kp_book_description) 4th Edition Book in chapter 1. problem 34. in pages 47-48.)

Comment: Bascially, no.  In order to determine the size of an x86 instruction you need to decode it -- there's no simple way of determining the size without pretty much a full decode.

Comment: Are you asking how you know how long each instruction is from looking at the asm source?  Why not just assemble and look at a listing, like `nasm foo.asm -l/dev/stdout`?  That will show you the address of every instruction.  Other than that, you just have to know whether that form of the instruction takes a modrm byte or not, and how long the immediate (if any) will be.  For 8086, the actual opcode (not including the operands) is always 1 byte.  Later x86 introduced some `0f xx` 2-byte instructions, and later some other mandatory prefixes like `tzcnt` = `rep bsf`

Comment: Which version of x86 do you care about?

Comment: @PeterCordes using NASM is a really good solution and I've already put that into consideration, however, my textbook I think uses MASM assembler which I also mentioned in the question. masm and nasm assemblers have some differences so I had compile errors for my desired .asm file. That is a legitimate solution for small assembly codes even though I was looking for a more general solution. for your comment's second part, I will navigate more about it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I assume MASM has a similar listing option that shows the address for each instruction.  Of course normally you don't need to know the absolute address, you just put a label there so you can refer to it from elsewhere.  That's part of why we use assemblers instead of writing machine code by hand.  I only ever look at listings to see total size of instructions, if I'm optimizing something for code-size (especially [Tips for golfing in x86/x64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/132981))

Comment: @fuz I am new to this language so I'm not quite sure. but it has to be older than 2003 or 2000 (the 4th Ed. of the book which I mentioned). it uses 16-bit registers so I'm guessing the version belongs to the 1980s according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86). the assembly language seems to be compatible MASM assembler used in DOS.

Comment: @AryaParvizi Ok.  So I guess you might only care about the original 8086 processor then.  Newer processors have added additional instructions, making this decoding a lot more complex.  Get yourself a copy of the 8086 datasheet and write a rudimentary decoder for the instructions.  The instruction length depends on the opcode and (if present) the mode and r/m fields of the modr/m byte.

Comment: You could also try to actually get a copy of MASM, or find something compatible or close enough to work with more minor changes.  [UASM](http://www.terraspace.co.uk/uasm.html) is an open-source assembler that claims MASM compatibility.